# Magento 2.3.5-p1 the frontend is blank due to Content Security Policy

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I just upgrade my magento store from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5-p1.
my store is using static.domain.com and media.domain.com for deployed static and media contents.

Console error messages - example
[Report Only] Refused to load the stylesheet 'URL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive : ....

Looking forward to hearing from all of you soon!

Comment: I have same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module to collect CSP violations reports and convert its to the CSP rules to prevent warnings in browser console - [flancer32/mage2_ext_csp](https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp)

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.3.5, Magento supports Content Security Policy headers and provides ways to configure them per module.

Content Security Policies (CSP) are a powerful tool to mitigate against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and related attacks.

By default, Content Security Policy is configured in report-only mode, which allows merchants and developers to configure policies to work according to their custom code.

What you're currently seeing is report-only mode.

You can configure your own custom CSP rules by adding a csp_whitelist.xml to your custom module’s etc folder or theme folder.

You can find more using the link below:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

Comment: What about core modules that are using domains that don't appear to be whitelisted? After updating, I'm getting a console full of these reports about domains that seems like they should be whitelisted by default like paypal, google-analyatics.com, vimeo, youtube, etc. Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MagentoAaron yeah, that's what I am also not sure. and I also think that subdomains for static and media content should be whitelisted by default.